# Why am I losing my session on page changes?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, facebook-php-sdk

So I'm trying to integrate the PHP facebook SDK/API with codeigniter, because I love codeigniter, but for some reason I keep losing my facebook session as soon as I change pages from my base URL, I have printed the $_session and all i get is Array ( [fb_339393762762289_state] => cb8c201ed66ebcaa60407114aa92f001 ) any ideas why this is happening?

**Here is what my controller looks like:**

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

var $user;
var $log_in_url;
var $log_out_url;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('facebook');
    $perams = array(
        'scope' => 'user_about_me, read_friendlists',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/'
    );
    $this->user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    $this->log_out_url = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    $this->log_in_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($perams);

    print_r($this->user);
    print_r($this->log_out_url);
    print_r($this->log_in_url);
}

public function index() {
    if ($this->user) {
        try {
            $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $this->user = null;
        }
    }

    if ($this->user) {
        $data['logout_url'] = $this->log_out_url;
    } else {
        $data['login_url'] = $this->log_in_url;
    }
    $data['user'] = $this->user;
    $this->load->view('templet/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('main view');
    $this->load->view('templet/footer');
}

  public function account() {

  if ($this->user) {
  try {
  $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  error_log($e);
  $this->user = null;
  }
  }

    if ($this->user) {
        $data['logout_url'] = $this->log_out_url;
    } else {
        $data['login_url'] = $this->log_in_url;
    }
  $data['user'] = $this->user;
  $this->load->view('templet/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('account');
  $this->load->view('templet/footer');
  }
```

from what I can understand from the source code of the api is that it is in charge of handling sessions, so I don't understand why it keeps losing it.

I was thinking it could maybe have something to do with my Htaccess set up.. Ie. my url when i change pages looks like this www.example.com/index.php/controller_name/method_name/

also do i need to do anything with the $_GET vars? because that is one thing i noticed.. there seem to be some things passed in the URL, but they don't continue on to other pages.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am really at a loss.

Comment: Do you loose any other $_SESSION variable (set one by yourself) the same way or only FB's?

Comment: I have not tried setting my own sessions yet. thank you for giving me that idea. I did not even think to check that. I will try setting some of my own. I am wondering, why do my variables not hold the data from one page to another, because they do have global scope over the controller. so it seems like the data should still be there.

Comment: yep just checked and sessions work fine. if i do them through CI functions... do you think I should try adapting the facebook SDK to useing CI functions?

Comment: I do not use CI, only pure php :) If sessions are fine then something is missing from understanding of FB api. Sorry, it is almost 2 am, too late for me to dig deeper into your problem.

Comment: I appreciate you help. I quite understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was somewhat simple, I kept loosing my session data any time I changed pages, and it tuns out the solution was quite simple. in the config file of CI you have to put you websites base URL, and I put  and the session was being created for http://www.mysite.com/ so the php sdk/api created one session for the first url and another for the second.. thus i lost all of the data as soon as i changed pages. so it's a simple problem, but took a lot of trouble shooting.

Answer (score 1):

If you use CodeIgniter Session Library you must know that "The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data"

[CodeIgniter Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: I appreciate you answer, but i figured it out. it was my base site domain. it was missing the www. which meant it was setting two cookies, one for the http://  site.com" and one for http://  www.site.com"